# Run onevent function on non manual change or edit to cell - google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table where I used apps script functions to automatically change the Timeline to match the date under the do date column. The do date column is a static date that is generated when I first set the timeline column. The date never changes, and it is not updated by users.

I've been testing my function by manually editing the do date to see if the changes reflect on the timeline column, not thinking through that the date will never manually change.

For example I set the table up as the following last night (2/8/2023):

I set the Task 1 timeline for tomorrow which then generated a do date of 2/09/2022. I was hoping the next day (2/9/2023) the Timeline would have switched to Today.

[image]

I was hoping when I checked the next day (2/9/2023) the following changes to the timeline would happen:

Task 1 = Today
Task 2 = Today
Task 3 = Tomorrow
Task 4 = Today

If I go and manually update the do date of task 1 to 2/09/2023 the timeline will change to today, however that's not what I wanted my function to do. And I just now realized my mistake of using an on edit function. Is there an easy way to fix this?

My code

```html
function onEdit(event){
    var { range, source } = event;
    first();
    
  function first() {
  var colK = 11;  // Column Number of "K"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == colK) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column K
    //THIS WEEK DATA //
        var curr = new Date();
    var year = curr.getFullYear();
    var month = curr.getMonth();
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
    var last = first + 6;
    var firstnext = first + 7;
    var lastnext = firstnext + 6;
    var firstsoon = first + 14;
    var lastsoon = firstsoon + 6;
    var firstday = new Date(year, month, first).getTime();
    var lastday = new Date(year, month, last).getTime();
    var firstdaynext = new Date(year, month, firstnext).getTime();
    var lastdaynext = new Date(year, month, lastnext).getTime();
    var firstdaysoon = new Date(year, month, firstsoon).getTime();
    var lastdaysoon = new Date(year, month, lastsoon).getTime();
    var doDateTW = range.getValue().getTime();
    //
    //Get the Do date and current date then set as same time.
    var doDate = changedRange.getValue().setHours(12, 0, 0);
    let today = new Date().setHours(12, 0, 0)

    console.log((doDate/8.64e7)/7,today/7)
    
    //Get the difference of the 2 dates
    var dateDifference = Math.round((doDate - today) / 8.64e7);



    //Set value to dropdown depending on difference
    var group = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(), colK - 5);
    if (dateDifference == 0) {
      group.setValue("Today");
    } if (dateDifference == 1) {
      group.setValue("Tomorrow");
    }    if (doDateTW >= firstday && doDateTW <= lastday && dateDifference != 1 && dateDifference != 0 ) {
      group.setValue("This Week");
    }  if (doDateTW >= firstdaynext && doDateTW <= lastdaynext) {
      group.setValue("Next");
    }  if (doDateTW >= firstdaysoon && doDateTW <= lastdaysoon) {
      group.setValue("Soon");
    } 
  }
}

}
```

Comment: There is no onEvent function like this available

Comment: You could use a time driven trigger at midnight, to refresh your timeline dropdowns, maybe?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the values of column "F" by the values of column "K".
- You want to do this when the date is changed.

In this case, how about the following flow?

1. By the time-driven trigger, the script is run.

   - About the time-driven trigger, it has already been mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75402733/run-onevent-function-on-non-manual-change-or-edit-to-cell-google-apps-script#comment133048824_75402733).
2. When the script is run, the values of column "F" are modified by the values of column "K".

When this flow is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function installTrigger() {
  const functionName = "myFunction";

  ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().forEach((t) => {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
}

function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("K2:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const curr = new Date();
  const year = curr.getFullYear();
  const month = curr.getMonth();
  const first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
  const last = first + 6;
  const firstnext = first + 7;
  const lastnext = firstnext + 6;
  const firstsoon = first + 14;
  const lastsoon = firstsoon + 6;
  const firstday = new Date(year, month, first).getTime();
  const lastday = new Date(year, month, last).getTime();
  const firstdaynext = new Date(year, month, firstnext).getTime();
  const lastdaynext = new Date(year, month, lastnext).getTime();
  const firstdaysoon = new Date(year, month, firstsoon).getTime();
  const lastdaysoon = new Date(year, month, lastsoon).getTime();
  const today = new Date().setHours(12, 0, 0);
  const values = range.getValues().map(([k]) => {
    if (k instanceof Date) {
      const doDateTW = k.getTime();
      const doDate = k.setHours(12, 0, 0);
      const dateDifference = Math.round((doDate - today) / 8.64e7);
      if (dateDifference == 0) {
        return ["Today"];
      } else if (dateDifference == 1) {
        return ["Tomorrow"];
      } else if (doDateTW >= firstday && doDateTW <= lastday && dateDifference != 1 && dateDifference != 0) {
        return ["This Week"];
      } else if (doDateTW >= firstdaynext && doDateTW <= lastdaynext) {
        return ["Next"];
      } else if (doDateTW >= firstdaysoon && doDateTW <= lastdaysoon) {
        return ["Soon"];
      }
    }
    return [null];
  });
  range.offset(0, -5).setValues(values);
}
```

- I used your showing script in the loop of `myFunction`.
- When `myFunction` is run, the values of column "F" are modified by the values of column "K".
- In this modification, the range of `sheet.getRange("K2:K" + sheet.getLastRow())` is used. Please modify this for your situation.

#### Install time-driven trigger.

Please run `installTrigger()`. By this, a time-driven trigger is installed. In this case, `myFunction` is run in 00:00 - 01:00 every day. If you want to set detailed times, this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75154901)