# Automatically disable a google form at certain point in time using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form which is open for responses through the week, please help me using apps script how can I disable the form that it is not accessible on every Friday 6 PM upto Monday 9 AM

and again be accessible back from Monday 9 AM through the whole week until Friday 6 PM.

and this should repeat every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to open your Google Form at 09:00 on Monday.
- You want to close your Google Form at 18:00 on Friday.
- Your Google Form is opening Monday to Friday.
- You want to run this day except for Saturday and Sunday.

In your situation, I remembered that this thread might be useful. [Ref (Author: me)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75153918) But, in that case, the script is run every day. I thought that modifying this script for your expected situation might be a bit complicated. So, I would like to introduce the modified script as an answer. When that script is modified for your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Google Form, and save the script.

When you run `init()` with the script editor, a time-driven trigger is installed. This trigger automatically runs the function `installTimeDrivenTrigger()` every day. But, in this case, the script is run on the days except for Saturday and Sunday by `if (["Saturday", "Sunday"].includes(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEEE"))) return;`. And, when this function is run, `start()` and `end()` functions are installed as the time-driven trigger.

`start()` enable Google Form at 09:00. And, `end()` disable Google Form at 18:00. And, after the next day, the function `installTimeDrivenTrigger()` is automatically run.

```js
const deleteTriggers_ = e => ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().forEach(t => {
  if (e.includes(t.getHandlerFunction())) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
});
const start = _ => FormApp.getActiveForm().setAcceptingResponses(true);
const end = _ => FormApp.getActiveForm().setAcceptingResponses(false).setCustomClosedFormMessage("Closed.");

function installTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  const d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEEE");
  if (["Saturday", "Sunday"].includes(d)) return;
  deleteTriggers_(["start", "end"]);
  if (d == "Monday") {
    const time1 = new Date();
    time1.setHours(9, 0, 0);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("start").timeBased().at(time1).create();
  } else if (d == "Friday") {
    const time2 = new Date();
    time2.setHours(18, 0, 0);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("end").timeBased().at(time2).create();
  }
}

// Please run this script. By this, installTimeDrivenTrigger() is run 00:00 - 01:00 every day.
function init() {
  deleteTriggers_(["installTimeDrivenTrigger"]);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("installTimeDrivenTrigger").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
  // end(); // If you want to close as the default situation, please use this.
}
```

- In this sample, when the user accesses the Google Form from 18:00 on Friday to 09:00 on Monday, "Closed." is shown. If you want to change this message, please modify the above script.

#### Note:

- In this modification, when the function name is changed, the script might not be able to be used when the function names in the script are not changed. Please be careful about this.
- I think that this script can be worked for your goal. But, in this script, `installTimeDrivenTrigger()` is run 00:00 - 01:00 every day by `ScriptApp.newTrigger("installTimeDrivenTrigger").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();`. If you want to run only Monday and Friday, please modify it as follows. By this, `installTimeDrivenTrigger()` is run on Monday and Friday.

  - From

    ```js
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("installTimeDrivenTrigger").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("installTimeDrivenTrigger").timeBased().everyWeeks(1).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY).atHour(0).create();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("installTimeDrivenTrigger").timeBased().everyWeeks(1).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY).atHour(0).create();
    ```

#### References:

- [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)
- [deleteTrigger(trigger)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger)
- [setAcceptingResponses(enabled)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setacceptingresponsesenabled)
- [setCustomClosedFormMessage(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setcustomclosedformmessagemessage)
- [Retrieving Names of Month and Day of Week using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/07/30/retrieving-names-of-month-and-day-of-week-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike-San, I want the from to be open from Monday 9 AM and continue to be open till Friday 6PM.  It should close from Friday 6PM and continue to be closed till Monday 9AM

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. In your situation, for example, do you want to close the Google Form from 18:00 on Monday to 09:00 on Tuesday?

Comment: No.
It should be open all the hours from Monday 9AM and continue to be open till Friday 6PM

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In the updated answer, Google Form is opened from 09:00 on Monday to 18:00 on Friday. And, Google Form is closed from 18:00 on Friday to 09:00 on Monday. Is this your expected situation?

Comment: Absolutely right  Tanaike - san, thats the situation I want

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. When you test this script and your expected situation is not obtained, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike -san, I change  ```time2.setHours(15, 0, 0);```  to test if the form closes on 3 PM afternoon, I checked and still the form is open.

Comment: @Alicia Stone About `I change time2.setHours(15, 0, 0); to test if the form closes on 3 PM afternoon, I checked and still the form is open.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. For example, When I tested `ScriptApp.newTrigger("end").timeBased().at(time2).create()` with `time2.setHours(15, 0, 0)` as `const time2 = new Date("2023-03-03 00:00:00")`, `end` function is installed at `2023-03-03 15:00`. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Alicia Stone By the way, although, unfortunately, I cannot know how you ran my script, as an important point, in my script, when you use this script, please run `init()` function as I have already mentioned in my answer. When you directly run the function `installTimeDrivenTrigger()`, the script might not be able to be correctly worked because of the time when `installTimeDrivenTrigger()` is run. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Missed this, it works now, I tested the script now and its inaccessible for the time I want and again makes it accessible when I want it to, Thank you as always @Tanaike - san

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I understood it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.